# Image as Plane no longer shows texture in object mode

Tags: image

I have just updated blender from v2.77a to v2.78.

When using image as plane the texture no longer shows in object mode after exiting wire frame mode.
Enabling "Textured Solid" under the display panel no longer works.

Is there an additional setting that is now needed to be enabled to view the texture in object mode again?

[video of this working in previous blender versions](https://youtu.be/Ub2a3kSfrw4?t=67)

Here is the addon that i am using.

[Image as Plane Addon](https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Add_Mesh/Planes_from_Images)

Comment: Blender doesn't show textures in Object Mode. Switch the viewport to Texture or Material Mode.

Comment: it used to work in blender v2.77a have a look at the question above. I have added a video showing it working in object mode.

Comment: I just downloaded latest 2.78 from the blender website: It still works in 2.78 , I'll add an image link here, since BSE police could soon delete my answer/comment below, http://amrc.altervista.org/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/images278.png. As I said before, it's not about the edit/object mode, it's about the viewport rendering mode: the image is visible even in edit mode (and also object mode)... but only if viewport shading is "texture", at least.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that the way you've been doing it is no longer supported. This should work:

[image]

Comment: You are correct It does seem like the method i was using is no longer supported

Answer (score 1):

[image: max draw type in properties panel]You can use the Draw Type for each object in the Properties panel to control them. Useful for working in wireframe in edit mode while actually keeping other objects as solid or textured, and this was why I made my [Drawtype Operator Pie menu addon](https://github.com/artistCDMJ/drawtype_operator_pie)

Answer (score 0):

@Samp (this is not an answer, but a way to put an image to a comment) it's not about the edit/object mode, it's about the viewport rendering mode: as you see below (2.76) the image is visible even in edit mode (and also object mode)... but only if viewport shading is "texture", at least.

[image]

My home notebook only runs 2.76 (old opengl card) but tomorrow will check with 2.78, and update this "mega-comment".